# Enforcing overriden equals/hashCode of TypeParameters. classTag[T].runtimeClass resolves to Nothing / No ClassTag available

Tags: scala, reflection, equals, hashcode

In a mixed Java/Scala environment, I have a parametrized class which requires its type parameters to override equals and hashCode properly. Thanks to [this blog](http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2009/10/java-puzzler-enforcing-whether-class.html) i coded up this method to check whether this is the case, using ClassTag:

```
 class SomeClass[KeyType, ValueType] (arg1: Converter[KeyType], arg2:Converter[ValueType]) {
 // concrete values of KeyType/ValueType not available at construction time

 enforceEqualsHashImpl
 // enforceEqualsHashImpl[KeyType, ValueType] : "error: No ClassTag available for KeyType "

 def enforceEqualsHashImpl[KeyType : ClassTag, ValueType : ClassTag]= {

  def checkEqualsEqualsHash[T](c:Class[T]): Boolean = {

    def checkequals[T](c:Class[T]):Class[_] ={
      val equalsDeclaringClass = c.getMethod( "equals", classOf[Object]).getDeclaringClass();
      if ( classOf[Object].equals( equalsDeclaringClass ) )
        throw new Exception( "HazelIndex7 parametrized by key class" + c + " which does not override equals")
      equalsDeclaringClass
    }

    def checkHash[T](c:Class[T]):Class[_] ={
      val hashCodeDeclaringClass = c.getMethod( "hashCode").getDeclaringClass();
      if ( classOf[Object].equals( hashCodeDeclaringClass ) )
        throw new Exception( "HazelIndex7 parametrized by key class" + c + " which does not override hashCode")
      hashCodeDeclaringClass
    }

    val equalsDeclaringClass = checkequals(c)
    val hashDeclaringClass = checkHash(c)
    val equals = equalsDeclaringClass.equals(hashDeclaringClass)
    if (!equals)
      throw new Exception("Equals in class " + c + " is implemented by "+ equalsDeclaringClass + " but hashCode is implemented by: " + hashDeclaringClass );
    equals
  }

  checkEqualsEqualsHash(classTag[KeyType].runtimeClass)
  checkEqualsEqualsHash(classTag[ValueType].runtimeClass)
}
```

However, i get this exception:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:     scala.runtime.Nothing$.equals(scala.runtime.Nothing$)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
```

It seems to me, that the type parameters cannot be resolved by ClassTag.runtimeClass for some reason? 
Is there something wrong with this code? What may have caused this exception?

Also tried things like this:

```
enforceEqualsHashImpl[KeyType, ValueType](classTag[KeyType], classTag[ValueType])
def enforceEqualsHashImpl[KeyType , ValueType ](implicit kc:ClassTag[KeyType],vc:ClassTag[ValueType])= ...
```

this resulted in:

```
error: No ClassTag available for KeyType
enforceEqualsHashImpl[KeyType, ValueType](classTag[KeyType], classTag[ValueType])    

error: No ClassTag available for ValueType ....
```

Maybe relevant: Note that the type parameter must be inferred indirectly by constructor arguments (arg1/arg2), which are not concrete values of the type parameters.

Are there any better means to check equals/hashCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** First of all, you shouldn't have declared type parameters in method `enforceEqualsHashImpl`, because they shadow `KeyType` and `ValueType` parameters declared in your class and I guess this wasn't your intention. So the declaration of your method should just be:

```
def enforceEqualsHashImpl {
  ...
}
```

Also, type parameter `T` in your inner methods also seems a bit redundant for me.

Now about the `ClassTag`s:

If you want the Scala compiler to provide `ClassTag`s for type parameters, you *must* at some point specify concrete type parameters. This is because information about type parameters is available only at compilation time (type erasure).

If you want your example to work, you need to pass `ClassTag`s to your class:

```
class SomeClass[KeyType : ClassTag, ValueType : ClassTag]
```

Otherwise your method, `enforceEqualsHashImpl`, cannot possibly know what actual types hide behind `KeyType` and `ValueType`.

And of course after this change, since your class requires `ClassTag`s for its type parameters, you must construct it in one of two ways:

- by passing concrete type parameters (e.g. `new SomeClass[String,Integer](keyConv, valueConv)`)
- do it somewhere where `ClassTag`s are already available, e.g. in a method like this one:

  ```
  def constructSomeClass[KeyType: ClassTag, ValueType: ClassTag] = 
    new SomeClass[KeyType,ValueType](keyConv, valueConv)
  ```

  Of course, in this case `constructSomeClass` also must be called with concrete type parameters or somewhere, where `ClassTags` are already available, and so on...

So, summarizing - you *must* specify concrete type parameters at some level if you want `ClassTag`s available automatically for your types.

Of course you can also create `ClassTag`s manually from `Class` objects like this:

```
val classTag = ClassTag(classOf[String])
```

so I guess if you had runtime classes of `KeyType` and `ValueType` available at the moment of `SomeClass` construction, you could do something like this:

```
def constructSomeClass[KeyType,ValueType](keyClass: Class[KeyType], valueClass: Class[ValueType]) = 
  new SomeClass[KeyType,ValueType](keyConv, valueConv)(ClassTag(keyClass), ClassTag(valueClass))
```

This is of course roughly equivalent to passing `Class` object themselves instead of `ClassTag`s.

Comment: @ ghik: thanks for your insight. Why is it I get a Runtime error in the first case? Shouldn't that be captured at compile time?

Comment: @ib84, you have shadowed `KeyType` and `ValueType` in `enforceEqualsHashImpl` method which means that in your code, `KeyType` and `ValueType` declared in `SomeClass` are not the same as `KeyType` and `ValueType` declared in `enforceEqualsHashImpl`, which is probably not what you wanted (see my edit). And you called your method like this: `enforceEqualsHashImpl` (without type parameters) which was translated by compiler to `enforceEqualsHashImpl[Nothing,Nothing]`

Comment: @ ghik: I see. I tried out different combinations of which the shown one is just one. I'm convinved now my approach cannot work and also a bit disappointed about the praised TypeTags. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ib84 That is JVM's dreaded type erasure. Language designers can't do much about it.